# How does static_cast behave when cast to a totally different class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I was making some excercise for learning inheritance and virtual methods in c++.
So i found myself into this:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void f() const {cout << "A::f";}
    virtual void g() {cout << "A::g"; m();}
    virtual void h() {cout << "A::h"; f();}
    void m() {cout << "A::m"; f();}
    virtual A* n() { cout << "A::n"; return this;}
}

class B : public A{
public:
    virtual void f() const {cout << "B::f";} //override
    void g() {cout << "B::g"; A::n();} //override
    virtual void m() {cout << "B::m"; f();}
    A* n() { cout << "B::n"; return this;}
}

class C : public A{
public:
    virtual void f() {cout << "C::f";} //new method cause misses const
    void g() const {cout << "C::g"; m();} //new method cause added const
    void m() {cout << "C::m"; g(); f();}
}



***
A*q3 = new C();
(static_cast<B*>(q3->n()))->f(); //solution is A::n  A::f
***
```

So is this an error from the book or is it right? For me, from my knowledge, i would mark this as an "Undefined Behaviour", but if i am wrong, how does this work?

Comment: *"So is this an error from the book or is it right?"* - What did the book say exactly?

Comment: `is this an error from the book` such code is in the book? You mind sharing what book is that?

Comment: The code doesn't compile

Comment: The goal of this excercise is to tell what will be the output: if it compiles, then what would be in the console output, if does not copile then maked as "NC", if there are runtime errors/undefined behaviours then marked as "?". 
I do not own the book, its a section shared by my professor (and i do not know the name or other), and what i've commented is the solution provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This casts a `C*` object to an `A*` object (via `n()`) and then casts an `A*` object to `B*` object. Finally it calls a **virtual** function.

So what happens in practice? The compiler will look to the virtual table of the underlying object and find there what function `f` to call. The virtual table is an actual table in memory. So all the casting from A to B to C has no influence on the data in the table.
There is no undefined behaviour, and indeed `A::f` will be called.

However, this works only for **virtual functions**. If the code were to call a member function of B using a C object, and if that function were to make use of member data available in B but not in C, all hell will break loose. Welcome to C++, where the ability to shoot yourself in the foot is a desired feature.

Comment: Not so sure about the UB claim. The standard says in [expr.static.cast] (C++17: 5.2.9(11)): “If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.” I read that as: the object must actually be of the cast-to type or a derived type, otherwise UB is invoked.” In the presence of a devirtualizing optimizer that seems like a reasonable requirement.

Comment: But if this work for the reason that you explain, then is the same for this? 
`(static_cast<C*>(q2))->g(); //soulution is "?" (undefined behaviour/run time error)`
where q2 is `A*q2 = new B();`

Comment: i think i answer myself reading again this `If the code were to call a member function of B using a C object, and if that function were to make use of member data available in B but not in C, all hell will break loose`

Answer (score 1):

[From cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/):

> static_cast can perform conversions between pointers to related
> classes, not only from the derived class to its base, but also from a
> base class to its derived. This ensures that at least the classes are
> compatible if the proper object is converted, but **no safety check** is
> performed during runtime to check if the **object being converted is in
> fact a full object of the destination type**. Therefore, it is up to the
> programmer to ensure that the conversion is safe. On the other side,
> the overhead of the type-safety checks of dynamic_cast is avoided.

You could easily cast to an object with more fields than the original, though the real object you point to is shorter. Then when you try to access those fields, it's like a buffer overflow - can yield very surprising results. Be very careful when doing this.